# Green cactus identification

Tags: identification, cactus

What is the name of this cactus? I'm planning to replant it and want to do it properly accordingly to its species.

[image: Green cactus] [image: Green cactus]

Comment: The exact species doesn't really matter. It's a "desert cactus" (i.e. not a "tropical rainforest cactus") so it wants maximum possible sunlight. Water it in summer, and give it *no water at all* for about four months in winter to let it have a dormant period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echinopsis species. Not so sure about the exact variety. Cactus likes gritty potting mix or well draining medium. Those type of species requires full sun exposure to maintain its shape. They become etoilated  when they cannot received enough sunlight. When watering use the "soak and dry" method. When the medium is bone dry, it's the right time to water your plant. Water generously and deeply. Every quarter you can feed them nutrients. Complete fertilizer suitable for cactus is available online. Hope it helps.